# JUnit5: Trouble Finding AssertEquals

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, junit5, junit-jupiter

I've set up JUnit in IntelliJ IDEA and have a bunch of tests with nothing in them.  When I run them, they all pass as expected.  However, when I type "assertEquals", it shows up in red.  When I hover over it, it says "Cannot resolve method."

I've googled around and it looks like I need to do:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

However, when I start typing `import static org.junit.`, the next options are "*", "jupiter", or "platform"...

For reference, here's what a sample test looks like in my IDE:

```
@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
void isButton() {
    assertEquals()
}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The full path to `Assertions` class is:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals
```

Ensure you have added [Jupiter API](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api) to your dependencies:

**Gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.0")
}
```

**Maven:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>5.9.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

There is a nice guide for Intellij IDEA and JUnit 5.
Take a look at it: [Using JUnit 5 in IntelliJ IDEA](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/08/using-junit-5-in-intellij-idea/)

Answer (score 0):

## Maven

Verify your dependency specified in your POM file. You should have following nested within your `dependencies` element.

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0-RC1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

If calling the assertions outside of your test classes, in your regular app classes, drop the `<scope>test</scope>` element.

### Example class

Here is an example trivial test.

```
package work.basil.example;


import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

/**
 * Unit test for simple App.
 */
public class AppTest 
{
    /**
     * Rigorous Test :-)
     */
    @Test
    public void shouldAnswerWithTrue()
    {
        assertTrue( true );
    }
}
```

### New `junit-jupiter` artifact

Note that as of 5.4.0 of JUnit, we can specify the new and very convenient single Maven artifact of [`junit-jupiter`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter) which in turn will supply 8 libraries to your project.